# SVG - problem in animating the wheel element

Tags: svg

The wheel element moves left and right using animate.
Then I point attributeName="transform" type="rotate" ,attributeName="transform" type="scale". 1 Element rotates. 2 The element is scaled. I want to see the car's wheel spin, but this element starts to fly.
Help me please.

I'm trying to add additive="sum" but it doesn't help in my attempts, and I also use transform="translate(-500 -500)".
Unfortunately I can't get the desired result.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="1000px" height="1000px" version="1.1" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision" image-rendering="optimizeQuality" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
 <g id="Слой_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
<g transform="translate(500 500)">
<rect id="shape4" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill="#6699FF" x="45.67" y="509.35" width="512.08" height="126.25">
<animate attributeName="x" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
45.67;455.04;45.67;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="y" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
509.35;509.35;509.35;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="width" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
512.08;512.08;512.08;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="height" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
126.25;126.25;126.25;"></animate>
</rect>

  <circle id="shape98" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill="#47285F" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="141.9" cy="640.02" r="60.04">
<animate attributeName="cx" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
141.9;551.28;141.9;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cy" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
640.02;640.02;640.02;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="r" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
60.04;60.04;60.04;"></animate>
</circle>

  <path id="kol2" fill="#75578C" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M141.67 584.18c-5.96,0 -8.91,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.25,1.2 2.89,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.91,0.02 7.64,0.51 11.41,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.92,-1.49 -2.26,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.81,-1.99 -14.89,-2.01zm-39.01 38.7c0.93,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.58,-6.39 -2.96,-4.33 -9.5,-3.73 -11.61,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.4,9.41 -4.16,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.08,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.86,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.72,-4.04 1.52,-7.22 3.18,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.16 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.02 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.95,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.46,0.24 4.91,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.65,-4.21 -0.03,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.83 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.33,4.1 0.85,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.06,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.49,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.39,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.2,3.87 -0.89,7.6 -2.1,11.28z">
<animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
M141.67 584.18c-5.96,0 -8.91,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.25,1.2 2.89,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.91,0.02 7.64,0.51 11.41,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.92,-1.49 -2.26,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.81,-1.99 -14.89,-2.01zm-39.01 38.7c0.93,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.58,-6.39 -2.96,-4.33 -9.5,-3.73 -11.61,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.4,9.41 -4.16,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.08,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.86,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.72,-4.04 1.52,-7.22 3.18,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.16 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.02 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.95,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.46,0.24 4.91,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.65,-4.21 -0.03,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.83 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.33,4.1 0.85,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.06,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.49,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.39,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.2,3.87 -0.89,7.6 -2.1,11.28z;M551.05 584.18c-5.96,0 -8.92,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.25,1.2 2.89,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.91,0.02 7.64,0.51 11.41,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.92,-1.49 -2.27,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.9,-1.35 -9.82,-1.99 -14.89,-2.01zm-39.01 38.7c0.92,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.59,-6.39 -2.95,-4.33 -9.49,-3.73 -11.6,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.4,9.41 -4.17,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.09,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.86,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.71,-4.04 1.51,-7.22 3.18,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.17 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.01 -16.34zm35.86 62.39c-2.24,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.94,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.47,0.24 4.92,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.66,-4.21 -0.02,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.84 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.33,4.1 0.85,5.83 3.16,4.54 10.06,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.57,-4.82 2.48,-9.74 2.72,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.38,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.04,1.17 -1.62,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.19,3.87 -0.88,7.6 -2.09,11.28z;M141.67 584.18c-5.96,0 -8.91,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.25,1.2 2.89,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.91,0.02 7.64,0.51 11.41,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.92,-1.49 -2.26,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.81,-1.99 -14.89,-2.01zm-39.01 38.7c0.93,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.58,-6.39 -2.96,-4.33 -9.5,-3.73 -11.61,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.4,9.41 -4.16,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.08,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.86,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.72,-4.04 1.52,-7.22 3.18,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.16 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.02 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.95,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.46,0.24 4.91,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.65,-4.21 -0.03,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.83 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.33,4.1 0.85,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.06,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.49,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.39,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.2,3.87 -0.89,7.6 -2.1,11.28z;"></animate>
</path>

  <circle id="shape3" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill="#47285F" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="458.86" cy="640.02" r="60.04">
<animate attributeName="cx" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
458.86;868.24;458.86;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="cy" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
640.02;640.02;640.02;"></animate>
<animate attributeName="r" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
60.04;60.04;60.04;"></animate>
</circle>
<g>
  <path id="kol1" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill="#75578C" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M458.64 584.18c-5.97,0 -8.92,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.24,1.2 2.88,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.9,0.02 7.63,0.51 11.4,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.91,-1.49 -2.26,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.81,-1.99 -14.88,-2.01zm-39.02 38.7c0.93,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.58,-6.39 -2.96,-4.33 -9.5,-3.73 -11.61,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.39,9.41 -4.16,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.09,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.85,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.71,-4.04 1.51,-7.22 3.17,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.16 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.02 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.95,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.46,0.24 4.92,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.65,-4.21 -0.03,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.84 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.34,4.1 0.84,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.07,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.49,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.38,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.19,3.87 -0.89,7.6 -2.09,11.28z">
<animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
M458.64 584.18c-5.97,0 -8.92,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.24,1.2 2.88,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.9,0.02 7.63,0.51 11.4,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.91,-1.49 -2.26,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.81,-1.99 -14.88,-2.01zm-39.02 38.7c0.93,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.58,-6.39 -2.96,-4.33 -9.5,-3.73 -11.61,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.39,9.41 -4.16,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.09,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.85,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.71,-4.04 1.51,-7.22 3.17,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.16 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.02 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.95,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.46,0.24 4.92,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.65,-4.21 -0.03,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.84 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.34,4.1 0.84,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.07,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.49,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.38,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.19,3.87 -0.89,7.6 -2.09,11.28z;M868.01 584.18c-5.96,0 -8.92,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.25,1.2 2.89,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.91,0.02 7.64,0.51 11.41,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.92,-1.49 -2.27,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.82,-1.99 -14.89,-2.01zm-39.01 38.7c0.92,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.59,-6.39 -2.95,-4.33 -9.49,-3.73 -11.6,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.4,9.41 -4.17,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.09,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.86,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.71,-4.04 1.51,-7.22 3.18,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.17 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.01 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.59,1.07 -3.94,3.22 -2.91,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.47,0.24 4.92,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.66,-4.21 -0.02,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.87,-0.39 -7.53,-1.25 -11.17,-2.64zm55.83 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.33,4.1 0.85,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.06,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.48,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.39,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.71,4.16 -0.19,3.87 -0.88,7.6 -2.09,11.28z;M458.64 584.18c-5.97,0 -8.92,7.3 -4.62,11.45 1.24,1.2 2.88,1.86 4.62,1.86 3.9,0.02 7.63,0.51 11.4,1.54 5.79,1.54 10.5,-4.67 7.43,-9.87 -0.91,-1.49 -2.26,-2.5 -3.95,-2.97 -4.89,-1.35 -9.81,-1.99 -14.88,-2.01zm-39.02 38.7c0.93,-2.09 0.69,-4.5 -0.58,-6.39 -2.96,-4.33 -9.5,-3.73 -11.61,1.06 -2.07,4.71 -3.39,9.41 -4.16,14.49 -0.84,6.18 6.48,10.02 11.09,5.83 1.16,-1.08 1.85,-2.41 2.09,-3.98 0.71,-4.04 1.51,-7.22 3.17,-11.01zm-12.19 -5.33l-4.16 14.49 13.18 1.85 -9.02 -16.34zm35.87 62.39c-2.25,-0.85 -4.72,-0.45 -6.58,1.07 -3.95,3.22 -2.92,9.57 1.85,11.36 4.78,1.83 9.56,2.94 14.65,3.45 2.46,0.24 4.92,-0.94 6.24,-3.04 2.65,-4.21 -0.03,-9.72 -4.98,-10.2 -3.88,-0.39 -7.54,-1.25 -11.18,-2.64zm55.84 -26.42c-0.64,2 -0.34,4.1 0.84,5.83 3.17,4.54 10.07,3.52 11.81,-1.72 1.58,-4.82 2.49,-9.74 2.73,-14.81 0.23,-6.24 -7.38,-9.35 -11.59,-4.74 -1.05,1.17 -1.63,2.59 -1.7,4.16 -0.19,3.87 -0.89,7.6 -2.09,11.28z;"></animate>
</path>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
</g>
  <polygon id="shape2" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill="#6699FF" points="175.27,374.26 419.21,374.26 504.07,500.52 99.35,500.52 ">
<animate attributeName="points" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
175.27,374.26 419.21,374.26 504.07,500.52 99.35,500.52 ;584.65,374.26 828.59,374.26 913.44,500.52 508.72,500.52 ;175.27,374.26 419.21,374.26 504.07,500.52 99.35,500.52 ;"></animate>
</polygon>

  <polygon id="shape1" transform="translate(-500 -500)" fill="aqua" points="198.97,386.1 397.19,386.1 466.14,488.69 137.27,488.69 ">
<animate attributeName="points" fill="freeze" begin="0ms" dur="3000ms" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" repeatCount="indefinite" values = "
198.97,386.1 397.19,386.1 466.14,488.69 137.27,488.69 ;608.34,386.1 806.56,386.1 875.52,488.69 546.65,488.69 ;198.97,386.1 397.19,386.1 466.14,488.69 137.27,488.69 ;"></animate>
</polygon>
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0.5;1" dur="5" repeatCount="1" additive="sum" />
</g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this is what you want to achieve but I would like to show you how you can simplify your code:

1. Instead of animating every shape you can put everything inside a group `<g id="car"` and you can animate this group. In this case I'm translating the #car  using `animateTransform`

```
<animateTransform 
   attributeType="xml" 
   attributeName="transform" 
   type="translate" 
   dur="5s" 
   values="-500,0; 1200,0" 
   repeatCount="indefinite"
/>
```

2. For the wheels, instead of those complicated paths I'm using a circle with a  thick stroke and a stroke-dasharray atribute. Please observe that both circles for the wheel have the same center (cx="458.86" cy="640.02") and the group is rotated around the center of the wheel (from="0 **458.86 640.02**" to="360 **458.86 640.02**")

```
 <g>
      <circle id="shape3" fill="#47285F" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="458.86" cy="640.02" r="60.04">
      </circle>
      <circle id="kol1" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="20 50.7" cx="458.86" cy="640.02" r="45">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 458.86 640.02" to="360 458.86 640.02" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
    </g>
```

This is an example:

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 300 1000 450" height="90vh">
  <g id="car">
    <rect id="shape4" fill="#6699FF" x="45.67" y="509.35" width="512.08" height="126.25">
    </rect>

    <polygon id="shape2" fill="#6699FF" points="175.27,374.26 419.21,374.26 504.07,500.52 99.35,500.52 ">
    </polygon>

    <polygon id="shape1" fill="aqua" points="198.97,386.1 397.19,386.1 466.14,488.69 137.27,488.69 ">
    </polygon>

    <g>
      <circle id="shape98" fill="#47285F" cx="141.9" cy="640.02" r="60.04">
      </circle>
      <circle id="kol2" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="20 50.7" cx="141.9" cy="640.02" r="45">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 141.9 640.02" to="360 141.9 640.02" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
    </g>
    <g>
      <circle id="shape3" fill="#47285F" fill-rule="nonzero" cx="458.86" cy="640.02" r="60.04">
      </circle>
      <circle id="kol1" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="15" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="20 50.7" cx="458.86" cy="640.02" r="45">
        <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 458.86 640.02" to="360 458.86 640.02" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform>
      </circle>
    </g>

    <animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="5s" values="-500,0; 1200,0" repeatCount="indefinite" />

  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you!
You pointed me in the right direction.
You missed type="scale", and for me the whole problem started precisely because of this))
It turned out like this:
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="5s" values="250,250; 0.0" repeatCount="1" />
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="translate" dur="2s" additive="sum" values="-50.0; 50.0; -50.0" repeatCount="indefinite" / >
<animateTransform attributeType="xml" attributeName="transform" type="scale" additive="sum" values="0.5;1" dur="5" repeatCount="1" />

Comment: If it didn't work for you, take the example above and ask another question using the animation you like. I will be glad to help. If you know how to make it work, please answer your own question. It will be helpfull for many.

Comment: Everything worked out for me.
I achieved the desired result using your code.
The whole problem was that I needed to add a magnification of all elements in the center and my approach to writing the code was wrong since I am a stupid newbie in this matter.
I am writing through a translator so it may be difficult for you to understand me.
Everything works as it should, thanks!